# IE9 Doesn't Adjust DIV Width Until Mouse-over/jQuery Selector Function

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have noticed a strange issue in using IE9 + twitter bootstrap 2.0.2 for CSS in IE9

When the page renders, if I don't move the mouse, I have DIVs that render with a huge width, I was sometimes able to test it with the console as width of 222448.

If I move the mouse, or for example call: `$('.selector').focus();` or `$('.selector').width()` on the elements, the width immediately reflects the accurate width per the stylesheet.

This behaves normally in Chrome,FF,Safari, and IE8, I've only seen it in IE9

I am using the `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` and it seems to be happening consistently to a parent element (its in Salesforce, so the html renders inside of a parent 'table' within the context of a larger page.

But what selector in bootstrap would cause the width of a 'div' to display in the hundreds of thousands of pixels in width!?